# how to solve " SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) "

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I don't know what happened but I got this error and I don't know how to solve it .
I tried to add a new user to mysql 'user@localhost' but it didn't solve it .

here's my .env :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=amarrakech
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=
```

can anyone please help me I need to solve this as fast as possible, and sorry if i couldn't provide much info just tell and I'll provide anything .

Comment: If you add a new user, you have to give it access to the database and set the priveliges. Normally your local mySQL has a user "root" that has full access. Note that you have to clear the config cache when changing the .env file

Answer (score 0):

check your config\database.php file or if you are running your project in local then mostly username is root, try DB_USERNAME=root

Comment: i am actually running my project in local and changing the username to root didn't help

Comment: @monaimmatlaya did you clear the config cache? php artisan config:cache

Comment: @GertB. yes I just cleared the cache using clear:cache

Comment: run php artisan config:cache just like Gert B. suggested after you change the db_user to root

Comment: @GertB. thank you so much all i had to do is to run the config:cache to solve it

Comment: You can use other commands like cache:clear
      **php artisan cache:forget**, 
      **php artisan cache:table**, 
      **php artisan config:cache**, 
      **php artisan event:cache**,       
      **php artisan route:cache**, 
      **php artisan view:cache**  
In case, in future if you think you need to delete cache then you can use any of these commands

Comment: @monaimmatlaya you're welcome. Laravel has many cache types, You can clear them all with php artisan optimize:clear , but i prefer to just clear the one i've made changes to: config:cache when i change config files, route:cache when i change the routes, ...

Comment: Thank You. I didn't know about it and using all cache clear commands when I want to clear cache **php artisan optimize:clear** this command is really useful

Answer (score 0):

When adding a new user to MySQL, you have to allow it to use the database with:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON yourdatabase.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

You also should use a password for *any* user

```
ALTER USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'New-Password-Here';
```

In general, when creating a user, you can specify the password in the GRANT statement:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON yourdatabase.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```